# FileOutputStream writes 0 bytes to Google Drive

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-contentprovider

**Step 1:** Get the file I would like to save (in this case a small png).

```
var fileBytes = getFileBytes();
```

**Step 2:** Get a content uri from google drive.

```
var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionCreateDocument);
intent.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryOpenable);
intent.SetType(mimeType);
intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraTitle, fileNameWithExtension);
StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "Select Save Location"), 43);
```

**Step 3:** Create a `FileOutputStream` to handle writing for the content provider.

```
protected override async void OnActivityResult (int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    base.OnActivityResult (requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == Result.Canceled && requestCode == 43) {
        using (var pFD = ContentResolver.OpenFileDescriptor(data.Data, "w"))
        using (var outputSteam = new FileOutputStream(pFD.FileDescriptor))
        {
            await outputSteam.WriteAsync(fileBytes);
        }
    }
}
```

This code works if I save the file locally. But when I save the file to Google Drive the file is there but it has 0 bytes. This is concerning because if i'm doing this right and it doesn't work on Google Drive then who knows if it will work on other content providers.

To be clear, it creates the file in Step 2. So is the code in Step 3 correct? Again, it does work if I save the file locally.

Comment: The uri you get from Google Drive is it a local path on the device or? Did you request permission to write to external storage before these actions?

Comment: That is a bug in the way Xamarin wraps Streams. Xamarin wraps the Java streams and returns a .Net steam and does not expose the actual Java stream...it drives me crazy as those are ***fubar*** for some Content Providers (Google Drive is just one that does not work properly w/ Xamarin). You have to only Java-based streams and then it will work correctly.

Comment: @Cheesebaron This is a content provider uri. You are granted "rw" temporary perms via the Content Provider (Drive in this case) since `ActionCreateDocument` was used. This is actually a "bug" in Xamarin converted Java->C# streams, been there for years....

Comment: @SushiHangover how do you get at the Java streams if they aren't exposed? btw I did try flushing and disposing the `outputStream` manually but obviously that didn't help.

Comment: @user875234 I've tried that also :-( `.Flush`.`.Close`/ using `ContentResolver.OpenFileDescriptor` vs. using the `.FileDescriptor` to get a stream, etc... It all results in the same thing, a zero byte file in some providers (FileProvider-based ones seem to always work, but the virtual ones like Drive typically fail). In Java, the stream code always works. I either use Java class reflection to get the `openOutputStream` method from the resolver and the `OutputStream` and `InputStream` classes or just write it in Java (Jar-library) and wrap it in a X.A binding library.

Comment: has this bug already been logged in Github somewhere? I feel like this needs to be fixed!